# What does averaging over time means in literature?

Tags: statistics, average

**Disclaimer:** This question is cross posted in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) because the answer might be field dependent.

Let $h: [0, L]\times \mathbb{Z}^1 \to \mathbb{Z}^1$ be a function, called the height function, and lets denote the mean value of $h$ at time $t$ be $\bar h(t)$.

In the paper *Anomaly in numerical integrations of the Kardar-Parisi-Zhang equation* by Chi-Hang Lam and F. G. Shin, Physical Review E, VOLUME 57, NUMBER 6, June 1998, at page 56, it is given that

> $$w := \left < \frac{ 1 \sum_{x=1}^L (h(x,t) - \bar h(t))}{ L}  \right
>  >^{1/2},$$
>
> where $L$ is the lattice size used in the numerical integration [...],
>   The brackets   denote ensemble averaging, which is equivalent to
>   averaging over time when steady state is being considered.

However, what do they mean by "ensemble average" and "averaging over time" ?

Comment: Check the comments on the cross-post...

Comment: I think you copied the wrong link for the "cross post".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis